# Does Kingfisher support video caching?

Tags: swift, kingfisher

I've scoured both the Kingfisher docs and Stack Overflow, and there is no clear answer to whether Kingfisher supports video caching. I'm new to caching videos/images in general, so if someone could expand on (1) whether caching videos with Kingfisher is possible? and (2) the difference between caching videos and images?

And if Kingfisher does not support video caching, a recommendation for tackling video caching would be appreciated. I'm using Firebase Storage for my videos, fyi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in Kingfisher's [GitHub](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) site:

> Kingfisher is a lightweight, pure-Swift library for downloading and
> caching images from the web. This project is heavily inspired by the
> popular SDWebImage. It provides you a chance to use a pure-Swift
> alternative in your next app.

Kingfisher is used for image downloading and caching only. If you want to cache video, Kingfisher can't help. By caching if you mean to store the video somewhere so that next time the user won't need to download again, simpliy store the video's in document folder.